# Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' MAGENTO

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, magento-1.9

Okay guys i am totally lost here..

So it says 1062. Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Here's my code.

```
INSERT INTO `admin_role` (`role_id`, `parent_id`, `tree_level`, `sort_order`, `role_type`, `user_id`, `role_name`) VALUES
(1, 0, 1, 1, 'G', 0, 'Administrators'),
(4, 1, 2, 0, 'U', 1, 'Admini'),
(6, 1, 2, 0, 'U', 2, 'Hans Jørgen'),
(7, 1, 2, 0, 'U', 3, 'Morten Munch'),
(9, 1, 2, 0, 'U', 5, 'Sarah'),
(13, 1, 2, 0, 'U', 8, 'alta'),
(14, 1, 2, 0, 'U', 9, 'Levi'),
(15, 1, 2, 0, 'U', 10, 'Hellen'),
(18, 1, 2, 0, 'U', 11, 'Lucy'),
(19, 1, 2, 0, 'U', 12, 'Daniel'),
(20, 1, 2, 0, 'U', 13, 'Kasper'),
(21, 1, 2, 0, 'U', 4, 'Martin'),
(26, 1, 2, 0, 'U', 16, 'H'),
(27, 1, 2, 0, 'U', 15, 'J'),
(28, 1, 2, 0, 'U', 14, 'K'),
(29, 1, 2, 0, 'U', 17, 'P');
```

Comment: Please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE admin_role`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But here https://gyazo.com/0e1b09777cc7fb54465c1bb24ce292f7 https://gyazo.com/345a3938658c13be886cc916e4afa9ef

Comment: `parent_id` for the first entry should probably be `NULL`, not `0`. Don't link to things that don't exist. Your problem is likely that the table already has data in it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Tadman, but it still didn't work.. Says the same :/

Comment: Then I would guess you already have a row in the table with `role_id=1`. The second time you try to insert the data shown above into the table, it will conflict with the data that is already in the table. In a primary key column, there can be only one row storing a given value.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up, from your screenshot:

[image]

Column role_id is the primary key of this table. Primary key cannot have duplicate value so for the error you get, it means that you already have one row in this table with role_id = 1. So your insert failed when you try with `(1, 0, 1, 1, 'G', 0, 'Administrators')`

As highlighted, it seems that your primary key is set to do auto increment. You can can simply insert values without that column and let the database figure out the next id.

You can try this code

`INSERT INTO`admin_role`(`parent_id`,`tree_level`,`sort_order`,`role_type`,`user_id`,`role_name`) VALUES
(0, 1, 1, 'G', 0, 'Administrators'),
(1, 2, 0, 'U', 1, 'Admini'),
(1, 2, 0, 'U', 2, 'Hans Jørgen'),
(1, 2, 0, 'U', 3, 'Morten Munch'),
(1, 2, 0, 'U', 5, 'Sarah'),
(1, 2, 0, 'U', 8, 'alta'),
(1, 2, 0, 'U', 9, 'Levi'),
(1, 2, 0, 'U', 10, 'Hellen'),
(1, 2, 0, 'U', 11, 'Lucy'),
(1, 2, 0, 'U', 12, 'Daniel'),
(1, 2, 0, 'U', 13, 'Kasper'),
(1, 2, 0, 'U', 4, 'Martin'),
(1, 2, 0, 'U', 16, 'H'),
(1, 2, 0, 'U', 15, 'J'),
(1, 2, 0, 'U', 14, 'K'),
(1, 2, 0, 'U', 17, 'P');`